# Ansible build report from json

Tags: json, csv, parsing, ansible, nested-loops

A PyATS Ansible playbook output is saved to a json file:

```
- name: Export variable to file
  copy:
    content: "{{ output }}"
    dest: "report.json"
```

The json content is as follows:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "structured": {
        "interfaces": {
          "Port-channel11": {
            "ipv4": {
              "neighbors": {
                "1.1.0.1": {
                  "ip": "1.1.0.1",
                  "link_layer_address": "0000.0000.00ca"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "GigabitEthernet1": {
            "ipv4": {
              "neighbors": {
                "1.1.1.2": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.2",
                  "link_layer_address": "0000.0000.00cb"
                },
                "1.1.1.3": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.3",
                  "link_layer_address": "0000.0000.00cc"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "item": {
        "key": "vrf1",
        "value": {
          "route_distinguisher": "1:1",
          "interfaces": [
            "GigabitEthernet1",
            "Port-channel11"
          ]
        }
      },
      "ansible_loop_var": "item"
    },
    {
      "structured": {
        "interfaces": {
          "Port-channel2": {
            "ipv4": {
              "neighbors": {
                "2.2.2.200": {
                  "ip": "2.2.2.200",
                  "link_layer_address": "0000.0000.00dd"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "item": {
        "key": "vrf2",
        "value": {
          "route_distinguisher": "2:2",
          "interfaces": [
            "Port-channel2"
          ]
        }
      },
      "ansible_loop_var": "item"
    }
  ],
  "skipped": false,
  "msg": "All items completed",
  "changed": false
}
```

I would like to create a csv file from this json file that contains the following data:

```
{{ ansible_host/inventory_host }},vrf1,Port-channel11,1.1.0.1,0000.0000.00ca
{{ ansible_host/inventory_host }},vrf1,GigabitEthernet1,1.1.1.2,0000.0000.00cb
{{ ansible_host/inventory_host }},vrf1,GigabitEthernet1,1.1.1.3,0000.0000.00cc
{{ ansible_host/inventory_host }},vrf2,Port-channel2,2.2.2.200,0000.0000.00dd
```

The closest I could reach has been:

```
    - name: Set vrflength variable
      set_fact:
        vrflength: "{{ output.results | length }}"

    - name: Set vrfmaxindex variable
      set_fact:
        vrfmaxindex: "{{ (vrflength | int) - 1 }}"

    - name: Create file
      lineinfile:
        insertafter: EOF
        dest: "report1.csv"
        line: "{{ inventory_hostname }},{{ output.results[ item | int ].item.key }},{{ output.results[ item | int ].structured.interfaces }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end="{{ vrfmaxindex }}"
```

```
`device1,vrf1,{"Port-channel11":{"ipv4":{"neighbors":{"1.1.0.1":{"ip":"1.1.0.1","link_layer_address":"0000.0000.00ca"}}}},"GigabitEthernet1":{"ipv4":{"neighbors":{"1.1.1.2":{"ip":"1.1.1.2","link_layer_address":"0000.0000.00cb"},"1.1.1.3":{"ip":"1.1.1.3","link_layer_address":"0000.0000.00cc"}}}}}

device1,vrf2,{"Port-channel2":{"ipv4":{"neighbors":{"2.2.2.200":{"ip":"2.2.2.200","link_layer_address":"0000.0000.00dd"}}}}}`
```

I'm unable to figure out how to build the required nested loops (for each VRF, for each interface and, for each neighbor, print the device name, the VRF name, the neighbour IP and the MAC on independent CSV lines).

Would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Just in case someone is interested in [**`ansible-pyats`**: 
`ansible-genie` is a implementation of the pyATS network testing framework in an Ansible role.](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/ansible-pyats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jinja. For example, the play

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    _csv: |
      {% for i in output.results %}
      {% set key=i.item.key %}
      {% for k,v in i.structured.interfaces.items() %}
      {% for n,l in v.ipv4.neighbors.items() %}
      {{ key }},{{ k }},{{ n }},{{ l.link_layer_address }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: report.json
        name: output

    - debug:
        var: _csv
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  _csv: |-
    vrf1,Port-channel11,1.1.0.1,0000.0000.00ca
    vrf1,GigabitEthernet1,1.1.1.2,0000.0000.00cb
    vrf1,GigabitEthernet1,1.1.1.3,0000.0000.00cc
    vrf2,Port-channel2,2.2.2.200,0000.0000.00dd
```